# C write async unsafe code in signal handler

Tags: c, signals

How can i run asynchrounous-unsafe code in a signal handler. I cant use a flag in my case. Could i use longjmp to jump to a different context?

Comment: Are you looking for [semaphore](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html) ? _"sem_post() is async-signal-safe: it may be safely called within a signal handler."_

Comment: The things i need are pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_cond_signal

Comment: Alas, _"Mutexes and condition variables are thus not suitable for releasing a waiting thread by signaling from code running in a signal handler."_. Maybe semaphore + pthread_mutex then ?

Comment: i found a solution. The frozen threads dont need to be efficient while waiting

Comment: For your question, regarding ISO C for longjump : _"As it bypasses the usual function call and return mechanisms, longjmp() shall execute correctly in contexts of interrupts, signals, and any of their associated functions. However, if longjmp() is invoked from a nested signal handler (that is, from a function invoked as a result of a signal raised during the handling of another signal), the behavior is undefined."_. Thus, OK in signal, but do not nest.

Comment: 'The frozen threads dont need to be efficient while waiting' umm.. I hope I never have to use your app:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a signal handler you can only use a set of safe functions which in many cases is sufficient for complicated functionality started within a handler. You can check man pages for your system for 'signal-safety' or similar. Here is a pointer on the web:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

pthread synchronization functions are not on the list.

However, One of the function listed there is `sem_post`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html

> sem_post() is async-signal-safe: it may be safely called within a
> signal handler.

So, you can implement mutex-like synchronization using semaphores within the signal handler.

Comment: Does sending a semaphore unit from a signal handler trigger an 'immediate' schedule/dispatch so that a waiting thread is set ready/running?

Comment: @MartinJames, It probably deserves a separate question.  sem_post just increments/decrements the counter in an atomic way. It might or might not wake up  other thread immediately, probably not. Could depend on implementation, as well as type of the signal, the thread which catches it and other factors, like signal masking.